# Can't Access Array below onCreate in costum adapter

Tags: java, android

I want to create listview with array when i place it up onCreate its workk.

```
String nama [] = {"Olala","bolabola","yolooo","fighter"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

but when i place it below onCreate "nama" cant read my array

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {





@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String nama [] = {"Olala","bolabola","yolooo","fighter"};


    ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView);
    CostumAdapter costumAdapter = new CostumAdapter();
    listView.setAdapter(costumAdapter);

}
public class CostumAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return nama.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.arablayout,null);

        TextView textViewName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview);

        textViewName.setText(nama[position]);



        return convertView;
    }

}
}
```

cannot resolve symbol nama 
I have to do it because I will create spannableString afterthis
any suggestion ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a constructer to `customView` class which includes a parameter to pass the array through:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String nama [] = {"Olala","bolabola","yolooo","fighter"};

        ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView);
        CostumAdapter costumAdapter = new CostumAdapter(nama);
        listView.setAdapter(costumAdapter);

}

public class CostumAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    String[] nama;

    public CostumAdapter(String[] nama){
        this.nama = nama;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return nama.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.arablayout,null);

        TextView textViewName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview);

        textViewName.setText(nama[position]);



        return convertView;
    }

}
}
```

Comment: OMG thanks you!! i am very new about java and android studio :-D

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare a function that can update the data in the adapter class, initialize a list in the `onCreate` method or whether you want and then call the function to update the data of the adapter.

Here's an example:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompactActivity {

    List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myList.add("firstString");
        myList.add("secondString");
        myList.add("thirdString");
        myList.add("fourthString");

        ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView);
        CostumAdapter costumAdapter = new CostumAdapter();
        customAdapter.updateList(myList);
        listView.setAdapter(costumAdapter);
    }

    public class CostumAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

        private List<String> myList = new ArrayList();

        public void updateList(List<String> newList) {
            this.myList = newList;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return myList.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.arablayout,null);

            TextView textViewName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview);

            textViewName.setText(myList.get(position));

            return convertView;
        }

    }
}
```